# How can I find the sender of an unrecognized selector in LLDB?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I'm getting an "unrecognized selector" error that is confusing me.

I know that I can "po" the pointer in LLDB to find out about the receiver.  But is there a way to deduce which object is sending this message?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a breakpoint set for Objective-C exceptions, the stack trace should show you the caller.

Comment: Agreed. See [Adding an Exception Breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html). I generally have the breakpoint look for any exception, and that generally does the job. Exception breakpoints are an under-appreciated Xcode tool.

Answer (score 0):

The command `bt` in the debugger will show you a backtrace (stacktrace), which should give you the class that initiated the message somewhere in that output.

Answer (score 0):

Backtrace doesn't always help if you're dealing with multiple threads - you end up with the backtrace of the exception handler on the main thread which isn't necessarily the one that cause the error.

However, since you know that the particular selector doesn't exist for a particular class, you can cheat a little by using a category to add the selector to the class, then just stick a breakpoint on it.

For example, for this error:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10004fb0
```

we know that something's trying to call "NSDictionary" with "isEqualToString". So, add this at the end of any file you like, outside any other "@implementation" blocks:

```
@implementation NSDictionary(debug)
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString*)theString {
    return FALSE;
}
@end
```

Stick a breakpoint on this, re-run your code and you will get a genuine stack trace. Don't forget to remove the category once you've found the error!